# SQL Server columns_updated() function - understand the result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, binary, hex, bitmask

I want to use the T-SQL `columns_updated()` function in my triggers to find out which cols were updated.

The thing is when reading the function output its:

```
0x0002000000000000000000
```

which indicated that column number 10 was updated, not sure how and why, what format is it and how it related to column 10 in the table.
I guess I am missing some knowledge in HEX, BITMASKS but just point me and I will be fine.

Can I have some help?

Is this an HEX string? if so i tries to convert it to binary using this link:
https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/hex-to-binary-converter.php
and the binary output was:
000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

but still how it correspond with column 10?

Thanks

Comment: If you're using this in an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger - it's much easier to just inspect the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables, join them based on the PK of the table, and check if the old ( `Deleted`) column is different from the new (`Inserted`) column value ....

Comment: thanks but i am just interested how to translate the output 0x0002000000000000000000
to the updated column index.
more a theoretic question to expand my knowledge

Comment: That's explained in the documentation, @dev , it actually has a really nice [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/columns-updated-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-using-columns_updated-to-test-the-first-eight-columns-of-a-table). Though, I will admit that, for me, `0x0002000000000000000000` doesn't translate to column 10, as `0x0002000000000000000000 & POWER(2, (10-1))` returns `0`.

Comment: @Larnu - you need to see the bit in the docs about more than 8 columns

Comment: Oops, missed the second example. Well, that shows me, @MartinSmith !

Comment: can you guys explain how it works?   i mean break it down step by step, hope its not too much.
what format is 0x0002000000000000000000
how to translate it to bits? if i separate it to bytes its:
00020000 
00000000 
000000 

is it a binary string? why do i see the number 2 then?

Comment: Did you read the linked documentation, @dev ?

Comment: For a single column, you may as well use `IF (UPDATE(yourCol))` instead of `COLUMNS_UPDATED`. Note that neither of them probably do what you think they do, they only show whether a column was present in the `update` statement, not whether rows actually changed. For that you need to compare `inserted` and `deleted` tables, which may have multiple rows in each

Comment: @Larnu yes i did i am just interested in the technical aspect of the function output:
0x0002000000000000000000
and how this translates to the columns index of 10.
it is HEX, BITMASK, BYTES, what procedure do i need to run on this output to get the index as decimal number?
i am just lacking some knowledge in related to BINARY

Comment: Again, it's all explain in the document I linked, @dev . Which part of that don't you understand and we can elaborate.

Comment: @Larnu
i understand that using the link you send i can extract the update column, but let me ask specific questions.
after updating column 10 in my table, this is the result of columns_updated():
0x0002000000000000000000
so:
1. for me this is just a string, what is it exactly? hex string? binary string?

2. what is the logical process i need to do on this string (manually) to extract the column 10?  for example, separate to 8 bits, calculate each bit to decimal value and so on.. until i reach the number 10.

Comment: `0x0002000000000000000000` isn't a string, it's a `varbinary`, as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/columns-updated-transact-sql) I linked tells you. To quote it: *"**Return types:** `varbinary`"*

Comment: yes i know i meant that for me its just a string, so i know binary string
 what is the logical process i need to do on this string (manually) to extract the column 10? for example, separate to 8 bits, calculate each bit to decimal value and so on.. until i reach the number 10

Comment: [binary and varbinary (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)... *" what is the logical process i need"* [Example B. Using COLUMNS_UPDATED to test more than eight columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/columns-updated-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-using-columns_updated-to-test-the-first-eight-columns-of-a-table) *"to do on this string"* Again, it's *not* a string, it's a `varbinary`.

Comment: thanks what is the logical process i need to do on this varbinary to extract the column 10? for example, separate to 8 bits, calculate each bit to decimal value and so on.. until i reach the number 10

Comment: ok, since its complicated to explain, let try a different approach, lets say i have a table with 4 columns and i updated col number 3, then i called the COLUMNS_UPDATED function, can you know what will be the output of that function? and if so how did you calculate it? separated all the table columns to group of 8 bits? found the updated bit, converted to decimal and then to hex? how about column number 9? some step by step similar to this: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6076/how-to-find-updated-column-in-sql-server-trigger/ will be helpful i just want to understand the theory

Comment: *" lets say i have a table with 4 columns and i updated col number 3, then i called the COLUMNS_UPDATED function, can you know what will be the output of that function?"* Yes, it would be `0x04`. As column 3 is the only column specified in the `UPDATE` statement, then the value of `COLUMNS_UPDATED`would be `POWER(2, (3-1))` (as explained in the documentation), which is `4`, or as a `varbinary` `0x04`.

Comment: forgive me guys, i didn't study computer science,  ok so 0x04 in binary is 0100 correct?
since its 8 4 2 1, so far so good. but the output is actually: 0x0400000000000000000000 so do I just ignore the rest of the zeros?

Comment: to be clear i am interested in the formula, lets say i update col 3 & 4, how do you know the function output, what's the logical formula running in your head?

Comment: another example why when i edit col 6 i get the following: 0x2000000000000000000000
 i would expect: POWER(2, (6-1)) = 32 it will be 0x32 ?